# FBA role in SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-2013, fba

Does adding an FBA role to SharePoint group makes the FBA users in the FBA role take the permissions from the SharePoint Group?

Is SharePoint able to resolve the users in the FBA role automatically?

For Example:

we have FBA role named FBARole1 and a user inside this role named FBAUser1.
From SharePoint we add FBARole1 to SharePoint Editors group.
Does FBAUser1 will take the permission levels from SharePoint Editors group?

Answer (score 0):

Not it will not, sharepoint role system is totally different than membership roles.

i would suggest to add the FBA (FBARole1) access to the SharePoint FBARole1, but you have to configure the Roles Picker in the web config(s).

Comment: Thank you @khaled Obaid for your reply. What do you mean by add FBA access to Sharepoint ?

Comment: Yes, sorry ... Please take a look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587357/sharepoint-groups-roles-using-fba