# How to use Roles with ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have a very basic flag (and thats all I need or want)
That when a users logs in to identify if that user is an administrator.

Ive never use Role(Role manager) before, so want it really simple.

Im my config I have

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
</roleManager>
```

on my login controller, (I want to do something very simple like)

```
 var usertoken = new UserToken(user.Id, user.AccountId, user.UserName, user.IsAdmin);
if(user.IsAdmin)
Roles.AddUserToRole(usertoken.UserName,"Admin");
```

but I just get an error saying "Unable to connect to SQL Server database."
Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the asp.net Role Management `tables` in your database?? Have you set your `ConnectionString` against the Role Manager??

Please have a look at these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164660(v=vs.100).aspx
[Asp.net User Roles Management: Where to Begin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452687/asp-net-user-roles-management-where-to-begin)

Once you have set these, you can use `Authorize` attribute or you could use User.Identity in everywhere